# How to design this custom drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hey I tried in several ways now to create following Drawer design:

[image: Drawer Design]

When I used a OverflowBox compared with a ClipOval somehow this design was the result:

```
ClipOval(
  child: OverflowBox(
    maxHeight: double.infinity,
    maxWidth: double.infinity,
    child: DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.backgroundColor
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: AppConstants.screenHeight,
        width: AppConstants.screenWidth,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Current Design Result]

How can i get the above design. I know it must be done for sure with a overflowbox and some kind of clipper but somehow I cant make it work.

Comment: You need to use Custom painter. Check this useful blog https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-draw-custom-shapes-in-flutter-aa197bda94bf

Comment: Probably this tutorial will help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niOTkLt14bE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that with a transparent drawer on which you paint over your shape with a `CustomPainter`. Make the drawer transparent by using a Theme and the `canvasColor: Colors.transparent` **Important**: Set the `elevation` of the drawer to 0, otherwise you see the edge of the transparent drawer.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
  body: Center(child: Text('Custom Drawer Shape')),
  drawer: Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      canvasColor: Colors.transparent,  // set the Color of the drawer transparent; we'll paint above it with the shape
    ),
    child: Drawer(
      elevation: 0,   // set elevation to 0, otherwise you see the transparent drawer a little bit
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: DrawerPainter(color: Colors.white), // this is your custom painter
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
            children: <Widget>[
              // Add your menu e.g. with ListTile
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

// Class which draws the custom shape
class DrawerPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;
  DrawerPainter({this.color = Colors.black});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = 3
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawPath(getShapePath(size.width, size.height), paint);
  }

  // This is the path of the shape we want to draw
  Path getShapePath(double x, double y) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(x / 2, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(x, y / 2, x / 2, y)
      ..lineTo(0, y);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawerPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.color != color;
  }
}
```